# Why does [1,2,3].prototype === Array.prototype return false?

Tags: javascript

I am playing with Prototype in my Chrome console.  Wouldn't `[1,2,3].prototype === Array.prototype` equate to the same prototype since they both contain the same methods?

Comment: `[].prototype` is undefined - but `[].__proto__ === Array.prototype` (warning, deprecated)

Comment: well, `[1,2,3].prototype` is undefined, for starters, so...no?  Did you mean `__proto__`?

Answer (score 4):

Non-Class objects don't have a `prototype` property. They instead have `__proto__`. So this works:

```
[1,2,3].__proto__ == Array.prototype
//=> true
```

But it's deprecated. If you really need to explicitly check the prototype, you can use this in modern JS engines:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf([1,2,3]) == Array.prototype
```

In general, however, the way to check if an object is an instance of a class is to use `instanceof`:

```
[1,2,3] instanceof Array
//=> true
```

Answer (score 3):

Older javascript engines (and current, but is considered deprecated)

```
[1,2,3].__proto__ === Array.prototype
```

Modern javascript engines (i.e. not IE)

```
Object.getPrototypeOf([1,2,3]) === Array.prototype
```

Comment: I've been trying to grasp this for the last 2 days and for some reason, this made it all click.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Add some extra points that deserves attention, `__proto__` is an internal property that is not encouraged to use, and only need to be implemented in browser environment according to language specification, `Object.getPrototypeOf()` is better.

Also you can do it by `isPrototypeOf`:

```
Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf([1,2,3])
```